# System of linear equations and Fredholm's alternative

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning linear algebra and bought the book from Gilbert Strange: Introduction to linear algebra and trying to understand the four fundamental subspaces. I know that a system is solvable if b is in the column space of A. A system is not solvable if there are numbers that multiply the equations in A so they add up to $0 = 1$

As he says, this is called Fredholm's law:

A system of linear equations is solvable if one of these problems has a solution: $Ax = b$ or $A^Ty = 0$ with $y^Tb = 1$

I don't really get the last part of this one. Lets assume I have a system of linear equations like the following: $$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&1&-1\\
1&0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}, b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
According to Fredholm's law the system is solvable if b is in $C(A)$ which is not the case in this example. But what about the second part? 
If I choose the following values for $y = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\\end{bmatrix}$ then $A^Ty = 0$ and $y^Tb = 1$.
But this system is not solvable. What am I understanding wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated, the system has no solution, since $b\notin C(A)$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative#Linear_algebra), **exactly one** must hold:

> $1)$ Either $Ax = b$ has a solution or
>
> $2)$ The equation $A^T y = 0$ has a non - trivial solution $y$, with $y^T b \neq 0$.

In the example you described, we are in  the second case, which means the proposition $1)$ cannot happen.

Equivalently, if we read the next line, the equation $A x = b$ has a solution iff for **any** $y$ s.t $A^T y = 0$, also holds $y^T b=0$.

---

As far as the book is concerned, could you provide the chapter which includes Fredholm's alternative?

Comment: It's in chapter 4.1 in the problem set, task 6 and 7. As far as I understand it now, either b is in C(A) and the system can be solved or there is a orthogonal vector to C(A) which dot product y^T*b = 1. If the second one is the case then there is no solution. When I asked the question I thought the system is solvable if one of the propositions Ax=b or A^T*y=0 with y^T*b=1 is true which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I tried to search online for the specific chapter, but I couldn't find it. However, I own the book *Linear Algebra and its Applications* by G. Strang and there is an exercise, which states (Fredholm's alternative):

*For every $A$ and $b$ **one and only one** from the following systems has a solution:*
$$(1)\:\:Ax = b; \quad\quad (2)\:\: A^Ty = 0, \, y^T b \neq 0.$$

Comment: I hope it is all clear now.